# What do the gas values mean in debug_traceTransaction?

Tags: go-ethereum, geth-debugging, transaction-trace

I know the struct logs contain the `gasCost` and the `gas` limit for each opcode.
In some cases like `CALL`, the gas cost appears to be aggregated from the opcodes below it. Also, all of the gas costs (for `CALL`s) are decrementing as you trace along the struct logs, and their values are determined by transaction's starting gas limit. However, it is difficult to calculate the actual gas cost for each `CALL`, as the numbers don't to add up expectedly. I am looking for a detailed explanation of how these gas values work throughout the structLogs in `debug_traceTransaction`. Every time I think I have discovered the meaning of the gas values in each `CALL`, my hypothesis is canceled because certain things are off by large margins, and the gaps in gas-costs seems also related to the starting gas limit.

I wish there was a simple example with a few `structLogs` showing the meaning and relationships between the gas fields as it traces along the `structLogs`. Can anyone educate me? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

-`gasCost` is the amount of gas the instruction is going to take

-`gas` is the amount of gas your transaction has left to use on each step, you can check it and you will note it is decreasing on each instruction

-calculating gas cost is a complex task, you can see it in `core/vm/gas_table.go` file in go-ethereum

-static gas costs are specified in `params/protocol_params.go` in go-ethereum

-the cost of event log is calculated in the function named `makeGasLog()` in `gas_table.go` ,very complex stuff so you can simplify if you think it depends on the size of the data in bytes

Answer (score 1):

a little bit complex, you can have a try.

the total gas cost of the transaction is calculated by **looping through** the struct logs and summing the gasCost values of all the opcodes in the called contract that are listed after the CALL opcode.

The total Ether cost of the transaction is then calculated by multiplying the total gas cost by the gas price of the transaction.

check the code:

```
pragma solidity ^0.6.0;

import "https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/";

// The contract that will be called by the transaction
contract CalledContract {
    // The function that will be called by the transaction
    function calledFunction() public {
        // Some code that consumes gas...
    }
}

// The contract that will call the CalledContract
contract CallingContract {
    CalledContract calledContract;

    constructor() public {
        calledContract = new CalledContract();
    }

    // The function that will call the CalledContract
    function callingFunction() public {
        // Call the CalledContract
        calledContract.calledFunction();
    }
}

// The contract that will call the transaction
contract TransactionCaller {
    CallingContract callingContract;

    constructor() public {
        callingContract = new CallingContract();
    }

    // The function that will call the transaction
    function callTransaction() public {
        // Create a Web3 instance
        Web3 web3 = new Web3(Web3.currentProvider);

        // Set the starting gas limit for the transaction
        uint256 startingGasLimit = 200000;

        // Set the gas price for the transaction
        uint256 gasPrice = 1 gwei;

        // Call the calling contract and get the transaction receipt
        TransactionReceipt receipt = callingContract.callingFunction.value(0).gas(startingGasLimit).send({
            value: 0,
            gasPrice: gasPrice
        });

        // Get the struct logs from the transaction receipt
        StructLog[] memory structLogs = web3.debug.structLogs(receipt);

        // Initialize the total gas cost to 0
        uint256 totalGasCost = 0;

        // Loop through the struct logs
        for (uint256 i = 0; i < structLogs.length; i++) {
            // Get the current struct log
            StructLog memory log = structLogs[i];

            // Check if the current opcode is a CALL
            if (log.op == "CALL") {
                // Loop through the remaining struct logs
                for (uint256 j = i + 1; j < structLogs.length; j++) {
                    // Get the current struct log
                    StructLog memory calledLog = structLogs[j];

                    // Add the gas cost of the current opcode to the total gas cost
                    totalGasCost += calledLog.gasCost;
                }
            }
        }

        // Print the total gas cost of the transaction
        console.log("Total gas cost: " + totalGasCost);

        // Calculate the total Ether cost of the transaction
        uint256 totalEtherCost = totalGasCost * gasPrice;

        // Print the total Ether cost of the transaction
        console.log("Total Ether cost: " + totalEtherCost);
```

Comment: Can you explain how you are importing a javascript file in Solidity? That seems really problematic.

Comment: the import statement is not actually importing a JavaScript file. Instead, it is using a string literal to specify the URL of a repository on GitHub that contains a JavaScript file. This is not the same as importing the JavaScript file itself into the Solidity contract.

Comment: What if the CALL makes several other CALLs to other contracts? How can I get the gas cost for each CALL individually using only the top-level receipt? It seems like this would add everything under the first CALL even if there were more. Also, how do you run a Solidity file that references a Javascript file like this?